# Proving a statement about an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

If $F$ is a field and $h$ is a polynomial over $F$ degree $\ge 1$, show that the mapping $f \rightarrow f(h)$ is a one-one linear transformation of  $F[x]$ into $F[x]$. Show that this transformation is an isomorphism of $F[x]$ if and only if $\deg h =1$.(Linear Algebra p.123 Qn 8 by Hoffman)

I have shown the  part that the transformation is one-one.

For the second statement, I can show the backward implication.

What is left to show is the forward implication: this linear transformation is an isomorphism implies that $\deg h =1$

Let $\phi : F[x] \rightarrow F[x]$ be the linear transformation.

Suppose $\phi$ is an isomorphism. I want to find a contradiction that when $\deg h \ge 2$, then $\phi$ is NOT surjective. I have used a simple exmple for $h=x^2+x+1$ to find some clue for proving this but I failed.

May anyone give some help ?

Thanks!

Best regards,
Michael.

Comment: If $h$ is of degree $d$, and the inverse $\psi$ of $\phi$ is given by $g\mapsto g(k)$, with deg$k=d'$. What is the degree $\psi \circ \phi (x)$?

Comment: I don't know if my interpretation is correct or not:
Let $\deg f = m$, $\deg h = d$, then $\deg (f(h)) =md$. We may choose some $g$ with  $\deg g$ not equal to multiple of $d$ for any $m$, this $g$ has no pre-image.

Comment: I mean if $\phi$ sends $x$ to $h$, then its inverse must send $h$ to $x$. And you may try to show that if $\deg h>1$, then no endomorphism of $F[x]$ can send $h$ to $x$, by degree argument.

Comment: @above,
Thanks! I think I understand now. I have a further question: The question has assumed that $\deg h \ge 1$. What happens to the cases for $\deg h=0$ and $h$ is a zero polynomial? The latter case is simple because in this case $\phi$ sends all $f$ to the constant term of $f$.$\phi$ is not injective. I am not very clear about the case when $\deg h=0$.

Comment: @luimicheal, if $\deg h=0$, then $h$ is a constant, and everything is mapped to the field $F$, so $\phi$ is not surjective.

Comment: @above, oh yeah! Simply take $g=x$ in $F[x]$, which has no pre-image.But I think $\phi$ should be injective? Suppose $f= \sum_{i=1}^n f_{i} x^{i}$. Then $f(h)=\sum_{i=1}^n f_{i} c^{i}$ is something like the representation of a number in base $c$.

Comment: $c^i$ are not linearly independent. For example, if $x$ is sent to some constant $c$, then $\phi (x) = \phi (c)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\deg f\circ h=\deg f \deg h$, so if $\deg h=0$ then $\deg f\circ h = 0$, if $\deg h>1$ then for all $f\in F[x]$ $\deg f\circ h \neq 1$, so if $\deg h\neq 1$ the mapping $f\mapsto f(h)$ is not surjective, therefore not an isomorphism, which proves the forward implication.